# Why are orthogonal quantum states represented as collinear in the Bloch sphere?

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises, bloch-sphere

We know that the angle between two orthogonal qubit states is 90 degrees. Why then, when we use the Bloch sphere, the angle becomes 180 degrees?

Comment: Note that phase of both states is zero. Transforming one state to another require angle $\theta$ to be 180 deg., not angle $\varphi$ representing the phase.

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8249/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/21689/55.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Bloch representation of states is what you get when you decompose density matrices in terms of a basis of orthonormal Hermitian operators.
That is, you write $\rho=\sum_k \sigma_k \langle\sigma_k,\rho\rangle$ where $\langle\sigma_k,\rho\rangle\equiv\operatorname{Tr}(\sigma_k\rho)$ and $\{\sigma_k\}_k$ is some basis of Hermitian operators. For single qubits, the standard choice is to use Pauli matrices, and write the decomposition as
$$\rho=\frac{I + c_x \sigma_x+ c_y \sigma_y + c_z \sigma_z}{2}.$$
Note that the coefficient of the identity matrix $I$ has been fixed to $\frac12$. This comes from the normalisation constraint on states, as $\langle I,\rho\rangle=\operatorname{Tr}(\rho)=1$.

Now, how does the inner product (and thus the geometry) between quantum states relate to the inner product between their Bloch representations?
Given pure states $|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_1\rangle$, and corresponding density matrices $\rho_1\equiv|\psi_1\rangle\!\langle\psi_1|$ and $\rho_2\equiv|\psi_2\rangle\!\langle\psi_2|$, with Bloch representations
$$\rho_i = \frac{I + \vec r_i\cdot \vec\sigma}{2},$$
we can see that
$$|\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle|^2 = \langle\rho_1,\rho_2\rangle = \langle\vec v_1,\vec v_2\rangle,$$
where  $\vec v_i=(\frac12,\frac12 \vec r_i)\in\mathbb{R}^4$, and thus
$$\langle \vec v_1,\vec v_2\rangle = \frac12(1+\langle\vec r_1,\vec r_2\rangle).$$
From this we can see that orthogonality of quantum states corresponds to orthogonality of the vectors $\vec v_i$, which corresponds to the translated vectors $\vec r_i$ being collinear, that is, to $\langle\vec r_1,\vec r_2\rangle=-1$.
The vectors $\vec r_i$ are what people typically mean when talking about the "Bloch sphere representation" of a state.

Comment: Why is the vector in the Bloch sphere, v_i, in R^4? Isn't the Bloch sphere in R^3?

Comment: @gary69 probably a typo, thanks. Fixed it